# Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy creando un perfil del lado usuario, para hacer noticias y publicarlas, cuando lleno los datos y le doy a guardar noticia me sale ese error. Estoy trabajando con codeigniter 4, aca es donde el codigo falla, los parametros de validacion los toma todos, el problema es al apretar guardar o publicar, ese error es el principal que no me permite crear la noticia  [image: Este es el formulario, la ultima parte es con ckeditor5]

```
 $("#btnGuardarNoticia").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            inputEstado = document.getElementById('estado');
            if (estado) {
                inputEstado.value = 1;
            } else {
                inputEstado.value = 0;
            }
            console.log("Valid: " + $("#formCrearNoticia").valid());

            var contenido = editorNueva.getData();
            var dataString = $("#formCrearNoticia").serialize();
            dataString += '&contenido=' + contenido;
            if ($("#formCrearNoticia").valid()) {
                var parametros=new FormData(document.getElementById("#formCrearNoticia"));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= base_url("panel/noticias/crear") ?>",
                    data: parametros,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data); //manejar resuesta
                    response = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (response["success"]) {
                        $('.txt_csrfname').val(response["token"]);
                        $("#modalCrear .close").click()
                        toastr.success(response["message"]);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            location.reload();
                        }, 1500);
                    } else {
                        $("#msjCrearNoticia").empty();
                        $('.txt_csrfname').val(response["token"]);
                        if (response["message"] != 'undefined') {
                            $("#msjCrearNoticia").append(response["message"]);
                        }
                        if (response["message"]['estado'] != 'undefined') {
                            $("#msjCrearNoticia").append(response["message"]['estado']);
                        }
                        if (response["message"]['fechaHora'] != 'undefined') {
                            $("#msjCrearNoticia").append(response["message"]['fechaHora']);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: Parece que estás usando la notación de jQuery para alcanzar el `form` por su id, prueba a quitar el `#` dejándolo sólo así: **`var parametros=new FormData(document.getElementById("formCrearNoticia"));`** Si sigue el error, pulsa en [edit] y coloca el HTML donde creas el `form`.

Comment: Hola! probe quitando el **#** pero me dio ese error, mas arriba le deje una imagen del mismo

Comment: Diría que la URL a la que estás enviando la petición Ajax: `"<?= base_url("panel/noticias/crear") ?>"` tiene, entre otras cosas, contenido Javascript. Es preciso entender que Ajax sirve para comunicar entre cliente y servidor y que el archivo que pones en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax, sobre todo cuando esperas un JSON, debe ser un archivo limpio, en puro PHP y en el cual controles bien lo que sale por pantalla. Ese archivo no debería tener código que se ejecutaría en el cliente, como podrían ser scripts o bloques HTML. Ese archivo es como una pasarela entre cliente/servidor.